# how to validate valid input only for operands in an equation

Tags: php

Guys how do i validate an operand input in php? im creating a very simple calculator page.. so '+' '-' and '.' are valid inputs too aside from number. so is_numeric is not enough validation. Also if you guys know a way in drupal to implement this validation feel free to post it. im using drupal by the way. And by the way here's my drupal code. i created a simple calculator module.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
  */

function calculator_menu(){
    $items['calculator-page'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('calculator_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,

    );
    return $items;
    }



function calculator_form(){

    $form['firstoperand'] = array(
    '#title' => t('First operand'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#rules' => 'numeric'
    );

    $form['operator'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(
        '+' => t('Plus'),
        '-' => t('Minus'),
        '*' => t('Times'),
        '/' => t('Divided by'),
    ),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    );


    $form['secondoperand'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Second operand'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#rules' => 'numeric'
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Generate',
    );

    $form['#submit'][] = 'calculator_form_submit';

    return $form;


    }

function calculator_form_submit($form, &$form_state){

    $firstoperand=$form_state['values']['firstoperand'];
    $operator=$form_state['values']['operator'];
    $secondoperand=$form_state['values']['secondoperand'];

    if(!is_numeric($firstoperand) || !is_numeric($secondoperand)){
        drupal_set_message("Must use numbers");
    }
    else{

    /*if($operator=='+'){

    $result= $firstoperand+$secondoperand;
    }
    if($operator=='-'){

    $result= $firstoperand-$secondoperand;
    }
    if($operator=='*'){

    $result= $firstoperand*$secondoperand;
    }
    if($operator=='/'){

    $result= $firstoperand/$secondoperand;
    }*/

    $result = $firstoperand+$operator+$secondoperand;




    drupal_set_message($result);

    }


    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Belmark, i dont know any Drupal but the php should be similar. The parts that you have commented out seem ok but you need to use 'else if' after the first 'if' in order to test properly. Where are you finding the errors?

Comment: @Martin, this is another problem sir. I have worked on that previous problem. Now i want to validate the input so that it can allow numbers, '+', '-', and '.' only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into using preg_match to find a regex pattern match for those symbols.
For example:

```
  1 <?php
  2 $subject = "1.00+2x3/4";
  3 $pattern = '/\.|\+|x|\//';
  4 preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
  5 print_r($matches);
  6 ?>
```

This would produce the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => .
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => +
                    [1] => 4
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => x
                    [1] => 6
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /
                    [1] => 8
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take advantage of the regex rule by using the [Drupal Form Api](http://drupal.org/project/fapi_validation) module

```
$form['firstoperand'] = array(
    '#rules' => 'regexp[/^((\+|\-)?[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?)|((\+|\-)?0?\.\d+)$/]'
    '#filters' => 'trim'
    );
```